# boostrap responsive photo grid cropping photos as page shrinks

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, react-bootstrap

I am pretty stuck, I have a bootstrap photo grid in a react app, in order to make photos of different sizes display the same size I added some style modifications. Full screen everything looks good but now the grid responsiveness is not working.

```
const photoHeight = { width: '100%',objectFit: 'cover'}

const photoDiv = {height: '315px',width: '270px'} 

<div class="row">
   {this.state.employees.map(employee =>    
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="team-item text-center">
           <div class="team-avatar" style={photoDiv}>
             <img style={photoHeight} class="img-responsive" src={employee.photo} alt=""/>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   )}
 </div>
```

As you can see in the photo below as I shrink the screen the photo width gets cropped (the height is fine I didnt want to show the faces in the photos)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should'nt there be a `class="img-fluid"` inside the img tag?

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?

Comment: Sorry, i did not see that option maybe because i have only 16 reputation points because i somehow lost my former profile ?!  :-(   I was looking for that one but now I know that i have simply not enought rep points to see it. ;-)